# How to handle cms elements registered with Admin SDK in Shopware v6.5.7.X?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

The following ticket has been processed in the new update v6.5.7.X:

https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/v6.5.7.0/changelog/release-6-5-7-0/2023-10-18-fix-that-multiple-instances-of-same-cms-element-from-app-sdk-are-not-working.md

In this update, the request URL of the CMS elements has also changed. With v6.5.7.0 it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/index?elementId=018bed02e090700d8123e8ee0917bf89&location-id=my-element
```

In previous versions, however, the `?shop-id`, `?shop-url`, `?shopware-shop-signature`, etc. were also provided as query parameters. These are of course essential in order to authenticate against the remote app server.

Therefore, our server currently sends back a `Shop id is not present in request!` error for every registered element in the shopping experiences.

Is this customization intentional, so that we have to adapt our app server accordingly? Unfortunately, I couldn't find any upgrade information on this.